# Shortest way to extract certain rows from DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need to extract certain rows from my dataset. The indeces of the rows I need are detected from another column in another variable. My dataframe is something like (with more columns)

```
1     data1
2     data2
3     data3
4     data4
5     data5
```

My other column is another variable and it's like

```
1     true
2     false
3     true
4     false
5     false
```

I put a boolean, moreover I need to check values in my column that satisfy a condition, I need those indeces and then I want to extract rows with those indeces from my dataset.

Comment: Use `df[df['boolean column']]`

Comment: I already saw the loc method but can I use it passing another variable different from my df?

Comment: Solution aboce is like `df[df['boolean column'] == True]`, but if compare with strings then need `df[df['boolean column'] == 'true']`. `loc` here is not necessary

Comment: I think you did not understand. I need to use another variable, something like `df1[df2['column name'] = 'something']`, but can I do this if `df2` is a serie?

Comment: OK, so change `something` to `True` or `true`, something missing ?

Comment: If `Series` then use `df[s == 'something']` but necessary same index values in `df` and `s`

Comment: Ok it works, I thought it was more difficult. Thanks.